# Multiple checkbox options on a PHP form

Tags: php, html, css, forms

have built a functional form with PHP however I have a checkbox with 5 options (more than 1 can be selected) however only 1 option is showing up in the email.

**HTML:**

```
<label class="radio"><input type="checkbox" name="service" value="Web Design" />Web Design</label>
<label class="radio"><input type="checkbox" name="service" value="Graphic Design" />Graphic Design</label>
<label class="radio"><input type="checkbox" name="service" value="Brand Identity" />Brand Identity</label>
<label class="radio"><input type="checkbox" name="service" value="Online Marketing" />Online Marketing</label>
<label class="radio"><input type="checkbox" name="service" value="Other" />Other</label>
```

**PHP: ($service)**

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$website = $_POST['website'];
$service = $_POST['service'];
$description = $_POST['description'];
$inspiration = $_POST['inspiration'];
$budget = $_POST['budget'];
$deadline = $_POST['deadline'];
$formcontent=" From: $name \n Email: $email \n Phone: $phone \n Website: $website \n\n service: $service \n budget: $budget \n deadline: $deadline \n\n description: $description \n\n inspiration: $inspiration ";
$recipient = "myemail@gmail.com";
$subject = "Contact form";
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
echo "Thank You, your information has been received.";
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have multiple elements with the same name then you will only be able to read one of them unless you use the array syntax `[]` e.g. `name=service[]` then you will receive $_POST['service'] as an array containing all your services. You can use [implode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) to convert it to a string.

```
$service = implode(' ', $_POST['service']);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use array in name, where you named it service write there, service[].
then use multiple="multiple" tag.and in php part use this:

```
<?php
$services=implode(',',mysql_real_escape_string($_post['service']));
print_r($services);
?>
```

Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

Put `name="service[]"` (Array) instead of `name="service"` in your form to get the multiple selected value as array. And while retrieving you could get the value using `implode` function as follows

```
$services = implode(",", $_POST['service']);
```

Answer (score 0):

User array name instead of simple name in checkbox like this :

```
<label class="radio"><input type="checkbox" name="service[]" value="Web Design" />Web Design</label>
<label class="radio"><input type="checkbox" name="service[]" value="Graphic Design" />Graphic Design</label>
<label class="radio"><input type="checkbox" name="service[]" value="Brand Identity" />Brand Identity</label>
<label class="radio"><input type="checkbox" name="service[]" value="Online Marketing" />Online Marketing</label>
<label class="radio"><input type="checkbox" name="service[]" value="Other" />Other</label>

print_r($_POST['service']);
// output
Array
(
    [0] => Web Design
    [1] => Graphic Design
    [2] => Brand Identity
    [3] => Online Marketing
    [4] => Other
)
```